# Bitmap is to large to be uploaded into a texture

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a app that uploads a picture made by the camera and upload it to a server.
But when i try to get it from the server into my imageview it says that the bitmap is to large ( in pixels )

How can i fix this?

```
new DownloadImageTask(imgProfile)
.execute("http://api.nl/local/index.php?action=get_user_profile_picture&username="
    + SaveSharedPreferences.user.getUsername()
    + "&password="
    + SaveSharedPreferences.user.getPassword()
    + "&user_number="
    + SaveSharedPreferences.user.getUserNumber());
```

This is my code that i use to process the image to the imageview:

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            try{
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch(OutOfMemoryError e){

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: `it says that the bitmap is to large` who says that? how?

Comment: Its shows up in LogCat "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into texture (2731x1820, max = 2048x2048" and my imageview stay blanc

Comment: FileOutputStream bmpFile = new FileOutputStream(finalPath);
    bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bmpFile);
50 is the shrink value

Comment: @MohammadAbuQauod: no. what you are suggesting would reduce the compressed jpeg size. the bitmap it self is not compressed in memory.

Comment: The pixels are to much, thats the problem, but i dont know how to fix that..

Comment: @KEVIN: this is a opengl limitation. you need a smaller image. Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of hardware acceleration. The system tries to load an extremely huge bitmap into an image view. If you have hardware acceleration turned on (e.g. via the Manifest) android will try to put the bitmap into an openGL texture, and your image is too big for this. It does not matter if you use JPEG or bitmaps for this, as the final openGL texture will have raw data and thus be a bitmap either way (each pixel is represented as it's own float values).

The only chance you have is to either download the image a lot smaller or resize it on the device. I'd go with the smaller download because it will also save the users's bandwith (and therefore costs)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i resize the pictures on the API side and that works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = null;

    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.outHeight = IMAGE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;//give some value
    options.outWidth = IMAGE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;//which is suitable for your app image size

BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, outPadding, options); //try this
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do i have to add in outPadding?

Comment: add some value since you know the height and width you can evaluate outPadding.